# Setting up cron in windows without getting a popup?

Tags: cron

I know that the scheduler can be used to create a cron job, but in my case, that job involves accessing a url. Problem is, if I use WGET or a batch file, a window keeps popping up. Any suggestions on how to get passed this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file that does what you want.  Let's say it's called `doit.bat`.  Create a file `doit.vbs` in the same directory.  It should have the following contents:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """doit.bat""", 0, False
```

Set the scheduler to run `doit.vbs`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed. I'd like to [cross link](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/07/episode-50-scheduling-stuff.html) you to a site, where this has been discussed while just pasting.

```
C:\> at [\\machine] HH:MM[A|P] [/every:day] "command"
```

Furthermore schtasks might be of help. You might want to use curl within a script. It has a specific "silent" function.